# Android Things DP6 & firebase-ui-auth incredibly slow

Tags: firebaseui, android-things

I was using the firebase-ui-auth with the previous version DP5.1 to login in on a Raspberry Pi, and it was working very well. The version used was:

firebase-ui-auth 2.4.0 and firebase 11.0.4.

After upgrading to the new DP6, the login works but the UI responds very very slow. The login activity appears after a couple of minutes. The new software keyboard works well (thanks google), but when pressing "next" on the login screens, the process takes an eternity. FInally, when finishing the login sometimes it returns to the previous activity (my app), and something the login activity is started again...

I updated the firebase-ui-auth to the version 3.1.0, with firebase 11.6.2, but that makes no difference.

Of course, in a normal android app that is using the same libraries, all works very well, because of that I think it should be an issue regarding the Android Things os...

Anyone has the same problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable hardware acceleration in your application manifest to speed up certain UI elements.